# PHP array inside an included page within a loop

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP page which returns an array. I have included the PHP page inside a loop in a different PHP page. I am getting the results of only the first array. It is printing nothing when i try to print the array after first iteration.

Page1:

Start of loop

include Page2

End of loop

Page2:

return array

result

printing only the first value in array

```
foreach($res->list as $Flist){
    Field($k,$fi);
}
```

Page1:

```
function Field($key, $Id){
    include('inp.php');
    print_r($S_array);
}
```

Page2: (inp.php)

```
$Deficit = f1();
for($i = 0; $i<20 ; $i++){
    $S_array[$i] = $Deficit;
}
function f1(){
  return $something;
}
```

Comment: please provide actual code

Comment: If you return the array from page 2, how are you assigning it in page 1?

Comment: The code is actually very lengthy, i cannot include it here

Comment: then only post the relevant code..?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Barmar i am trying to use the array in page 2 directly in page1 by just using the array name in page2

Comment: Then what do you mean by `return array`? Are you returning it or are you assigning it to a variable?

Comment: This is why we need to see some example code. Your description doesn't tell us what you're actually doing.

Comment: @Dagon i have added the  sample code please check it.

Comment: I tried your code, it printed the array every time through the loop. Are you sure you used `include`, not `include_once`?

Comment: @Barmar i tried both, nothing works

Comment: This is poor design to begin with. Define a function in the include file, include it just once, and call the function in the loop. The function should return the array, and you can assign it to a variable.

Comment: Turn on `error_reporting(E_ALL);`, see if you're getting any warnings.

Comment: @Barmar i have error_reporting() turned on. it does not show any warnings.

Comment: With your latest update, I'm getting an error "Cannot redeclare f1()". You can't include a file multiple times if it defines a function.

Comment: @Barmar So, is there any solution to overcome it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `f1()` function definition from `inp.php`. Otherwise, you get a fatal error due to trying to redefine the function each time you include it. Move its definition into Page 1, or some other file that you just include once.

But a better way to design the whole thing is to only define functions in your include files, and call them from the other files.

inp.php:

```
function get_S_Array() {
    $Deficit = f1();
    for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) {
        $S_array[$i] = $Deficit;
    }
    return $S_array;
}

function f1() {
    return $something;
}
```

page 1:

```
include('inp.php');
function Field($key, $Id){
    $S_array = get_S_array();
    print_r($S_array);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. Thanks a lot. I don't have reputation to thumps up sorry.

Comment: Accepting the answer is the way to indicate that it worked. Click the check mark.